Airflow: Failing to push data back into the pipeline
I have setup a workflow, which consists of two tasks:
In second, I am successfully pulling data pushed into the pipeline by the first task. However, after processing data, when I try to push data back into the pipeline, I get the error "INFO - Task exited with return code -9".
Here are the logs: 
Why is XCOM failing to push data into pipeline? How can I communicate data to other tasks?

Identified issue:
The problem was with the cross communication i.e. XCOM, which is not suitable for passing dataframes, and large amounts of data in the pipelines. Reference: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/xcoms.html

Solution:
Since we can not pass the data between tasks using XCOMs, we can use shared storage using which tasks can communicate data. The XCOMs can be used to pass the location of the files in shared storage so that other tasks can know from where to fetch data from.

Return code -9 is mostly associated with an out-of-memory error. For instance, how big is your data size compared to the worker memory executing the task "primary_transform_task"? Get rid of unused variables and optimize for memory, or get a bigger worker node to accommodate the big data. Also, remember that the best use of airflow is to orchestrate. Data processing for large datasets needs to happen on Spark clusters, for example.

The data that I read in task1 and push into the pipeline is of around 777MB, and I am able to pull it. After cleaning data in primary task, the data becomes 333MB. Pushing it into pipeline gives error

Check which XCOM backend you are using. Note: An XCom is identified by a key (essentially its name), as well as the task_id and dag_id it came from. They can have any (serializable) value, but they are only designed for small amounts of data; do not use them to pass around large values, like dataframes. Ref : https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/xcoms.html

Yeah got that... But I got two questions.... First... How can I pass data between 2 tasks, if not using XCOM.... second.... Why I am able to push/pull data in/from task1, but pushing causes error in task2
